# Meteor packages & variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, meteor, scope, package

My Meteor project is structured in packages only (there are several articles on the internet recommending and explaining on how to do this). I ran into a basic problem which I can not seem to solve. Here is the issue stripped down to a minimum test case:

I have two packages, 'one' and 'two' (created with 'meteor create --package' and added to the project subsequently) Package two holds a variable and exports this variable. Package one logs the contents of this variable to the console:

two.js:

```
two_var = 'two'
```

package.js (two):

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'two'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.addFiles('two.js', 'client');
  api.export('two_var', 'client')
});
```

one.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(two_var) //two_var found, unexpected
})

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(two_var) //two_var found, unexpected
}, 3000)

console.log(two_var) //two_var not found, expected
```

package.js (one):

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'one'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  //api.use('two', 'client');  //not using two, but two_var found in certain situations
  api.addFiles('one.js', 'client');
});
```

As you can see the variable from package two can be accessed in situations I would not expect so. Am I overlooking something or do I misunderstand the concept of the package?

Comment: and what are you expecting? You can find `two_var` after the package is loaded because you added it to your project `meteor add two` if you want to keep `two_var` private don't add the package to the meteor project and use `api.use('two', 'client')` this way it will be available in package `one` and not available to the app.

Comment: thank you - I thought that adding a package had to be done for every package used in your meteor project and was not aware of the two methods you described. Now I understand why things work the way they do - will dive in the details for some more comprehension